# How to add Javascript to IntelliJ

Tags: javascript, java, maven, intellij-idea

I have problem with add javascript to my editor intellij.

[image]

It does not detect the syntax of this language completely.

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript support is available in IntelliJ IDEA Ultimate edition, see [this page](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/features/editions_comparison_matrix.html).